# Не работает команда телеграм-боту на Пайтоне

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Я писал телеграм-бота, но у меня возникла проблема с командами "order", "commands" и "pricelist". Пишет, что не понимает меня (тоесть всё правильно, за исключнием конкретно этих команд).

Код следующий:

````
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('тут токен')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    mess = f'Привет, <b>{message.from_user.first_name}</b>'
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess, parse_mode='html')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['help'])
def help(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Мой создатель - начинающий програмист на пайтоне, который хочет начать на этом зарабатывать. В связи с низким уровнем его знаний в этой теме, расценки на содание ботов очень низкие. Если ты хочешь узнать о коммандах, доступных в боте - пропиши комманду "/commands". К слову, Профиль моего создателя в телеграме выглядит так - <b>@ilvntr</b>. Пожалуйста, пиши ему по делу, частенько он бывает занят :(', parse_mode='html')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_user_text(message):
    if message.text == "Привет":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'И тебе привет, <b>{message.from_user.first_name}</b>!', parse_mode='html')
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Я тебя не понимаю. Пожалуйста, если ты хочешь общаться со мной - используй команды, что полностью описаны в <b>"/commands"</b>', parse_mode='html')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
def get_user_photo(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Вау, крутое фото!')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['order'])
def order(message):
    markup = types.InLineKeyboardMarkup()
    markup.add(typesInLIneKeyboardButton("Оформить заказ", url="https://forms.gle/WCxdEKAkNvyxkRe6A"))

@bot.message_handler(commands=['pricelist'])
def pricelist(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '1. Бот для контроля чата. Возможности - кик по команде, выдача предупреждений, бан по команде. Время разработки - 1-3 дня. Цена - от 250 до 300 гривен.'
                                      '2. Бот для бизнеса или блога. Возможности - закрепит все ссылки на социальные сети и сайты в нескольких кнопках по одной команде. Время разработки - 1-3 дня. Цена - от 200 до 250 гривен.' , parse_mode='html')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['commands'])
def commands():
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '/help - Даёт тебе информацию о моём создателе. Ты можешь писать ему по поводу оплаты его работы после заполнения гугл формы. '
                                      '/order - Даёт тебе ссылку на гугл форму, в которой можно оформить заказ. '
                                      '/pricelist - Отображает прайс-лист моего создателя. Там указаны расценки для всех ботов. ', parse_mode='html')


bot.polling(none_stop=True)```
````

Comment: так и пишет - "Я не понимаю", или есть строка с текстом ошибки на английском?

Comment: @Сергей пищут комаду боту "order", или "commands" или "pricelist". Ответ бота "Я не понимаю" по логике данного кода. Автор данного кода тоже не понимает по чему так происходит. Короче не работет как задумано.

Answer (score 1):

1. commands

Может бить (но это не точно) в функции

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['commands'])
def commands():
```

Надо добавить аргумент message.

2. pricelist

[Почитайте о конкатенации срок](https://tproger.ru/translations/speedy-string-concatenation-python/)

И вместо этого:

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '/help - Даёт тебе информацию о моём создателе. Ты можешь писать ему по поводу оплаты его работы после заполнения гугл формы. '
                                  '/order - Даёт тебе ссылку на гугл форму, в которой можно оформить заказ. '
                                  '/pricelist - Отображает прайс-лист моего создателя. Там указаны расценки для всех ботов. ', parse_mode='html')
```

должно быть:

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '/help - Даёт тебе информацию о моём создателе. Ты можешь писать ему по поводу оплаты его работы после заполнения гугл формы. ' +
                                  '/order - Даёт тебе ссылку на гугл форму, в которой можно оформить заказ. ' +
                                  '/pricelist - Отображает прайс-лист моего создателя. Там указаны расценки для всех ботов. ', parse_mode='html')
```

3. order

Также вы кажется пишете неправильно

```
markup = types.InLineKeyboardMarkup()
```

Должно быть:

```
markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
```

Об этом можете прочитать [здесь](https://programtalk.com/python-examples/telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup/)

Comment: спасибо! приду домой  проверю!

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
...
@bot.message_handler(commands=['help'])
...
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
...
@bot.message_handler(commands=['order'])
...
@bot.message_handler(commands=['pricelist'])
...
@bot.message_handler(commands=['commands'])
....
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text']) # ВНИМАНИЕ на это участок кода должен быть 
...                                          # быть последним 

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```